# Java Generics Unexpected Behaviour for Constructor <X,Y> (C<Y>) and Interface C<Y>

Tags: java, eclipse, generics

I have the following code:

A class that models the mapping between a `ValueContainer<P>` and an Entity `E`. (Eg. a checkbox (ValueContainer) and something that has a Boolean value):

```
public abstract class ObjValContainerMapper<E, P> {

    private ValueContainer<P> provider;

    public ObjValContainerMapper(ValueContainer<P> provider) {
        this.provider = provider;
    }

    public abstract P getValue(E entity);

    public abstract void setValue(E entity, P value);

    ...

}
```

An interface `ValueContainer<P>`:

```
public interface ValueContainer<T> {
        T getValue();
        void setValue(T value);
}
```

A custom Checkbox:

```
public class AdvancedCheckBox extends JCheckBox implements ValueContainer<Boolean>
```

And some code that unexpectedly doesn't work:

```
AdvancedCheckBox chckbxBindToDrive = new AdvancedCheckBox(
            "Bind to Drive");

ObjValContainerMapper<IndexSpec, Boolean> bindToDriveMapper = 
        new ObjValContainerMapper<IndexSpec, Boolean>(chckbxBindToDrive) {
    @Override
    public Boolean getValue(IndexSpec entity) {
        if (entity == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return entity.isBindToDrive();
    }
    @Override
    public void setValue(IndexSpec entity, Boolean value) {
        entity.setBindToDrive(value);
    }
};
```

The code does not compile. The error shown is "**The constructor ObjValContainerMapper(AdvancedCheckBox) is undefined**". Eclipse suggests, among other options, to let AdvancedCheckBox implement ValueContainer or cast the argument chckbxBindToDrive to ValueContainer, despite AdvancedCheckBox explicitly declares `implements ValueContainer<Boolean>`.
Strangely enough I have reused code from an old project that was built with Java 6, in which case the approx. same code worked fine. Has something changed with Java 7 or am I missing something?

Environment:

- Eclipse Kepler
- JDK 1.7.0_51
- some code generated with WindowBuilder (the AdvacedCheckBox declaration)

Comment: Why don't you try compiling with 6 and see if it works?

Comment: Works for me on open-jdk-7

Comment: try following steps, right click on your project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Libraries tag -> Add Library -> JRE System Library -> Select Alternate JRE -> select jre that is installed in your system -> Finish

Comment: @jeremyjjbrown I cannot easily set the entire project to 6 as I am using features of 7 rather extensively so there is errors in any case. When setting it to 6 it seems the same error is still there. I also set-up a test project and copied the sources in which case it works fine with either 6 or 7. Could the issue maybe be related to WindowBuilder or Eclipse?

Comment: @sasankad Changing the library unfortunately didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: @bfour, try cleaning the project workspace (menu Project -> Clean...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thx for all the troubleshooting proposals in the comments.

The cause for this behaviour was that I copied the ValueContainer interface twice into two differnt packages as I assumed it would be missing given that Eclipse didn't seem to find it first (thx @sasankad for the proposal to clean the project). 
I hope this is still helpful for others as the error message and solution-proposals by the compiler and Eclipse respectively are not and are rather misleading.